# MPXJ (Java) could not read all the task items in the mpp file

Tags: mpxj

I am trying to read a mpp file using the mpxj library in java. For some files, the program reads perfectly without an issue, but on few files, program skips some tasks.

Does somebody have any similar experience?

The Mpp file can be checked from the below

There are around 58 Tasks, but the code only reads 14 tasks.

https://github.com/prathyush-aratla/filestore/blob/a379645200f8fde2d847f30030924ac23b9d9bfc/SampleCode

https://github.com/prathyush-aratla/filestore/blob/a379645200f8fde2d847f30030924ac23b9d9bfc/Sample_Corrupted_Project_Data.mpp

Comment: Hi, I've just checked with the latest MPXJ code from GitHub, and I'm seeing 59 tasks. Can you try with version 10.6.0 (the current release version) to see if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks, the latest one 10.6.0 worked. I am using 10.2.0. Hope this is due to a Microsoft update and then fixed in the mpxj.